# Running two tasks in parallel with GUI update

Tags: c#, async-await, dispatcher

I have downloaded the sample code for the async/await in C#

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Async-Sample-Example-from-9b9f505c

And now I have tried to adapt it to accomplish a different goal: I want to update the GUI while performing the `GetStringAsync`

So this is what I did and it works but I have some doubts about my code. If it is correct or the "right" way to do it.

1- Using `Task.WhenAll` to run two Task in parallel

2- Should the Task Method `UpdateUIAsync` that appends a dot every 200ms to the waiting text be done with the `dispatcher.begininvoke` or is this way ok?

3- Share use of field `finished` to synchronize behaviours, again, "ok" or is there a better approach?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // Mark the event handler with async so you can use await in it.
    private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call and await separately.
        //Task<int> getLengthTask = AccessTheWebAsync();
        //// You can do independent work here.
        //int contentLength = await getLengthTask;
        finished = false;
        int[] contentLength = await Task.WhenAll(AccessTheWebAsync(), UpdateUIAsync());

        resultsTextBox.Text +=
            String.Format("\r\nLength of the downloaded string: {0}.\r\n", contentLength[0]);
    }

    bool finished = false;

    // Three things to note in the signature:
    //  - The method has an async modifier. 
    //  - The return type is Task or Task<T>. (See "Return Types" section.)
    //    Here, it is Task<int> because the return statement returns an integer.
    //  - The method name ends in "Async."

    async Task<int> UpdateUIAsync()
    {
        resultsTextBox.Text = "Working ";
        while (!finished)
        {
            resultsTextBox.Text += ".";
            await Task.Delay(200);
        }
        resultsTextBox.Text += "\r\n";

        //Task<int> write = new Task<int>(() =>
        //{
        //    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        //    {
        //        resultsTextBox.Text = "Working ";
        //        while (!finished)
        //        {
        //            resultsTextBox.Text += ".";
        //            Task.Delay(200);
        //        }
        //        resultsTextBox.Text += "\r\n";
        //    }));

        //    return 1;
        //});

        return 1;
    }
    async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
    {
        // You need to add a reference to System.Net.Http to declare client.
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // GetStringAsync returns a Task<string>. That means that when you await the
        // task you'll get a string (urlContents).
        Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

        // The await operator suspends AccessTheWebAsync.
        //  - AccessTheWebAsync can't continue until getStringTask is complete.
        //  - Meanwhile, control returns to the caller of AccessTheWebAsync.
        //  - Control resumes here when getStringTask is complete. 
        //  - The await operator then retrieves the string result from getStringTask.
        string urlContents = await getStringTask;
        finished = true;
        // The return statement specifies an integer result.
        // Any methods that are awaiting AccessTheWebAsync retrieve the length value.
        return urlContents.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the 3rd question, have a look at ManualResetEvent Class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=netframework-4.7.2 or other thread syncronization helpers like Semaphore, EventWaitHandle, etc.

Comment: @Max - why? there is no multi-threading in this example... as all code runs on UI thread.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, hmmm... I'm not entierly sure on that. Under the bonnet, it uses `Task.Run`, which (as per its description) "Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool...". I agree, that `Task.Run` method is tending to re-use the current thread, not providing real mutlitasking, however, it may change if app is already using lots of tasks/threads, etc.

Comment: @Max what is "it" in "it uses `Task.Run`"? None of the code in the post nor code in MSDN sample uses `Task.Run` directly, neither `Task.Delay` nor `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` create threads at all (and again does not use `Task.Run`)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov. `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` uses `Task.Run`. `HttpClient` is not published on reference source web site, but I did disassemble in VS, and found this call inside `HttpHandler` (not sure about the class name, already closed all decompiled tabs)

Comment: @Max good to know... but that should not (assuming HttpClient is implemented reasonably) be observable from outside - all code in the post will run on the same thread and whatever HttpClient does on another thread should not be accessing shared data.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, yes, it uses evens, which should be "flattened" to the UI thread, so, take it as a pre-caution. Just in case. ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- Using Task.WhenAll to run two Task in parallel

The operations are running *concurrently*, and `Task.WhenAll` is the appropriate mechanism for asynchronous concurrency. All of your code runs on only one thread, so there's no true parallelism here.

> 2- Should the Task Method UpdateUIAsync that appends a dot every 200ms to the waiting text be done with the dispatcher.begininvoke or is this way ok?

`Dispatcher` is not necessary, since the code runs on the UI thread. However, I do recommend the `IProgress<T>` pattern [as Paulo recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55093158/263693) because that helps make your code more testable and less tied to a specific UI.

> 3- Share use of field finished to synchronize behaviours, again, "ok" or is there a better approach?

The unprotected shared field does work in this case since all your code is run on a single thread. However, I'd recommend using the `CancellationToken` pattern so that the semantics are clearer: when `AccessTheWebAsync` completes, your code wants to *cancel* `UpdateUIAsync`. Using an established pattern like that not only clarifies the intent but also makes the code more reusable.

Answer (score 1):

The `async-await` way of reporting progress is through the [IProgress Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) and it's implementation, the [Progress Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1).

If you change your `UpdateUIAsync` method to:

```
private async Task UpdateUIAsync(IProgress<string> progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        progress.Report(".");
        await Task.Delay(200);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.resultsTextBox.Text = "Working ";

    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        var task = AccessTheWebAsync();
        await Task.WhenAny(
            task, 
            UpdateUIAsync(
                new Progress<string>(s => this.resultsTextBox += s),
                cts.Token));
        cts.Cancel();
        var contentLength = await task;
    }

    this.resultsTextBox.Text +=
        String.Format("\r\nLength of the downloaded string: {0}.\r\n", contentLength);
}
```